# Problem on adding element with a loop for in an array in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

My goal is to separate each word from a string and store the separated words in an array.
Everything seems to be going well but the final table is only filled with the last word and I can't understand why.

Please find my code below:

```
enum {TAILLE_BUFFER = 100};

char  la_commande[TAILLE_BUFFER];
char* tableauArguments[TAILLE_BUFFER];
char* espace = " ";

printf("Rentrez la commande à executer avec ses arguments\n");
scanf("%[^\n]s", la_commande);
printf("%s\n", la_commande); 

int cpt = 0;
int dernier_espace = 0;
int lenTab = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < TAILLE_BUFFER; i++)
{
  if( (int)la_commande[i] == 0 ){
    break;
  }

  lenTab++;
}

for(int cpt1 = 0; cpt1 < lenTab + 2; cpt1++)
{
  int taille = cpt1 - dernier_espace;
  char le_mot[taille];
  
  if(la_commande[cpt1] == 32 )
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < taille; i++)
    {
      le_mot[i] = la_commande[i + dernier_espace];
    }

    printf("test1 :  %s %d\n", le_mot, cpt);
      
    tableauArguments[cpt] = le_mot;
    printf("test2 %s\n", tableauArguments[cpt]);

    dernier_espace = cpt1;
    cpt++;
  } 
}  

for(int cp1 = 0; cp1 < 5; cp1++)
{
  printf("\nLecture du tableau  : %s numero : %d", tableauArguments[cp1], cp1);
}
```

Comment: This code does not compile. Fix a [mre] and be more precise about the expected and actual output.

Comment: show some sample input and output

Comment: Here `char le_mot[taille];` The memory is reserved at the beginning of the loop, then freed at the end of the same loop.

Comment: I ask the user to enter a sentence and I want the program to separate the words of this sentence in a table.
input : "hello world !"

 output expect :
 tab[0]"hello"
 tab[1]"world"
 tab[2]"!"

 output actual :
 tab[0]"!"
 tab[1]"!"
 tab[2]"!"

Comment: @Damien, Yes because I try to put the value of le_mot in the array tableauArguments
And I don't know how to do other than this

Comment: You have to allocate some memory to `tableauArguments[cpt]` and then to copy the string in it (with `strcpy` for example).

Comment: char* tableauArguments[1000]; not enough ?

Comment: You are a genious I SUCCED THANKS

Answer (score 0):

you couldn't do that: `tableauArguments[cpt] = le_mot;` because you didn't allocate memory location for `tableauArguments[TAILLE_BUFFER]` double array. Even if you allocate, you have to use 'strcpy()' fucntion to copy content of a string array to another one.
The working code may be like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    char la_commande[100];
    char tableauArguments[100][100];
    char* espace = " ";
    printf("Rentrez la commande à executer avec ses arguments\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",la_commande);
    printf("%s\n",la_commande); 
    int cpt = 0;
    int dernier_espace = 0;
    
    int lenTab= 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    if((int)la_commande[i] == 0){
      break;
    }
    lenTab++;
    }

    for(int cpt1 = 0; cpt1 < lenTab+2; cpt1++) {
        int taille = cpt1 - dernier_espace;
        char le_mot[taille];
        if(la_commande[cpt1] == 32 )
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < taille;i++){
                le_mot[i] = la_commande[i+dernier_espace];
            }
            
            printf("test1 :  %s %d\n",le_mot,cpt);
            
            strcpy(tableauArguments[cpt], le_mot);
            
            printf("test2 %s\n",tableauArguments[cpt]);
            dernier_espace = cpt1;
            cpt++;
        }
    }  
    for(int cp1 = 0; cp1 < 5;cp1++){
        printf("\nLecture du tableau  : %s numero : %d", tableauArguments[cp1], cp1);
    }
}
```